# Execute an entire yaml task file one host after the other in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run `test.yaml`, which contains a lot of tasks. I expect that the first host in my inventory runs all tasks in `test.yaml` before moving to the next one. But the actual result is that each task in `test.yml` is run on all three hosts at a time. How to implement this function?

This is my inventoy

```
[host1]
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

This is my task file

```
---
# test.yaml
- name: task1
  shell: echo task1

- name: task2
  shell: echo task2

- name: task3
  shell: echo task3
```

And this is how I include the task file in my playbook

```
- name: Multiple machine loops include
  include: test.yaml
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  loop: "{{ groups['host1'] }}"
```

The actual result is

```sh
TASK [Multiple machine loops include] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/learn/main.yml for 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 => (item=192.168.1.1)
included: /home/learn/main.yml for 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 => (item=192.168.1.2)
included: /home/learn/main.yml for 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 => (item=192.168.1.3)


TASK [task1] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.11.1]
ok: [192.168.11.2]
ok: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task2] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task3] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.11.1]
ok: [192.168.11.2]
ok: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task2] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task3] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task1] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.11.1]
ok: [192.168.11.2]
ok: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task2] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task3] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.11.1             : ok=12   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0   
192.168.11.2             : ok=12   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0   
192.168.11.3              : ok=12   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

What I expect is：

```sh
TASK [task1]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1]

TASK [task2]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1]

TASK [task3]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1]



TASK [task1]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.2]

TASK [task2]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.2]

TASK [task3]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.3]


TASK [task1]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.3]

TASK [task2]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.3]

TASK [task3]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to play a set of tasks serially on a set of hosts. Vladimir's answer points out why your current implementation cannot achieve your requirement.

You could do that with an include and a loop (see below if you really need that for a particular reason), but the best way IMO is to use `serial` in your play as [described in the documentation for rolling upgrades](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

For both example below, I created a "fake" `inventory` file with 3 declared hosts all using the local connection type

```
[my_group]
host1 ansible_connection=local
host2 ansible_connection=local
host3 ansible_connection=local
```

## Serial run (preferred)

This is the `test.yml` playbook for the serial run

```
---
- name: Serial run demo 
  hosts: my_group
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: task1
      shell: echo task 1

    - name: task2
      shell: echo task 2

    - name: task3
      shell: echo task 3
```

And the result

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml 

PLAY [Serial run demo] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [task1] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [task2] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [task3] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

PLAY [Serial run demo] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host2]

TASK [task1] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]

TASK [task2] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]

TASK [task3] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]

PLAY [Serial run demo] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host3]

TASK [task1] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host3]

TASK [task2] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host3]

TASK [task3] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host3]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0   
host2                      : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0   
host3                      : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

## Include run (alternative if really needed)

If you really need to use include and delegate to a set of hosts, this would still be possible but you need:

- To change your included file to add `delegate_to` for each task with a variable.
- To target a single host in the play running your include and not your group of hosts like demonstrated in your question.

Note that in your question, you are using `include` which is already announce for future deprecation (see the notes on [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html)). You should prefer all the `include_*` and `import_*` replacements modules, in your case [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-module)

This is the `test_include.yml` file

```
---
- name: task1
  shell: echo task 1
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"

- name: task2
  shell: echo task 2
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"

- name: task3
  shell: echo task 3
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
```

This is the `test.yml` playbook:

```
---
- name: Include loop demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Include needed tasks for each hosts 
      include_tasks: test_include.yml
      loop: "{{ groups['my_group'] }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: delegate_host
```

And the result

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml 

PLAY [Include loop demo] *********************************************************************

TASK [Include needed tasks for each hosts] ***************************************************
included: /tmp/testso/test_include.yml for localhost
included: /tmp/testso/test_include.yml for localhost
included: /tmp/testso/test_include.yml for localhost

TASK [task1] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host1]

TASK [task2] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host1]

TASK [task3] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host1]

TASK [task1] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host2]

TASK [task2] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host2]

TASK [task3] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host2]

TASK [task1] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host3]

TASK [task2] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host3]

TASK [task3] *********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> host3]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=12   changed=9    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks, serial seems to be used only for play-book, not for task?

Comment: @cydia absolutely (see the documention link included in my answer), hence why I proposed the alternative `include_tasks` using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

'*include*' is not delegated. Quoting from [Delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation)

> Be aware that it does not make sense to delegate all tasks, debug, add_host, **include**, etc always get executed on the controller.

To see what's going on run the simplified playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Multiple machine loops include
      include: test.yaml
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['host1'] }}"
```

with '*test.yaml*'

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }}"
```

For example, with the inventory

```
host1:
  hosts:
    test_01:
    test_02:
    test_03:
```

the abridged output below shows that the included task run at localhost despite the fact that the task was delegated to another host.

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "localhost test_01"
}
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "localhost test_02"
}
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "localhost test_03"
}
PLAY RECAP 
localhost            : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The solution is to move '*delegate_to*' to the included task. The play  below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Multiple machine loops include
      include: test.yaml
      loop: "{{ groups['host1'] }}"
```

with the included task

```
- command: hostname
  register: result
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
- debug: var=result.stdout
```

gives (abridged):

```
TASK [command] 
changed: [localhost -> test_01]
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "test_01.example.com"
}
TASK [command] 
changed: [localhost -> test_02]
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "test_02.example.com"
}
TASK [command] 
changed: [localhost -> test_03]
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "test_03.example.com"
}
PLAY RECAP 
localhost              : ok=9    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Nothing to use `TASK [task1] *********************************************
ok: [192.168.11.1]
ok: [192.168.11.2]
ok: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task2] *********************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]

TASK [task3] *********************************************
changed: [192.168.11.1]
changed: [192.168.11.2]
changed: [192.168.11.3]
`