# Issues with multiple with_items in a task

Tags: ansible

I have a task which has multiple with_items and hence pick the latest defined item in the delegate which is not the expected result

```
- name: Add secondaries
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ groups['mongodb-active'] }}"
  shell: /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add("{{ item }}:27017"))'
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['mongodb-arbiter'] }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant have two `with_items` clauses. assuming you want to iterate the list `groups['mongodb-active']` and execute the shell module for each item in the `groups['mongodb-arbiter']` list, you could do it like that:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mongodb_active_list:
      - host1
      - host2
      - host3
    mongodb_arbiter_list:
      - json_a
      - json_b
      - json_c

  tasks:

    - name: print debug
      debug:
        msg: "running on host: {{ item.0 }}, shell module with argument: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ query('nested', mongodb_active_list, mongodb_arbiter_list) }}"
```

**UPDATE**:

after understanding better the requirement, the task i would suggest is:

```
- name: Add secondaries
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['mongodb-active'][0] }}"
  shell: /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add("{{ item }}:27017"))'
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['mongodb-arbiter'] }}"
```

it will delegate the task to the first host of the `mongodb-active` group (which is supposed to have only 1 host as clarification states), and iterate the task for all the hosts of the `mongodb-arbiter` group.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, active group has only host 1 server , so I need to use active group with delegate_to so that shell execution command of rs.add on host 2 and host3 (added to group arbiter) runs only on host 1(active). Hope you got my requirement.

Comment: sorry, but not sure i got the requirement. you want to run the shell module on host1 1 time per host of orbiter group ?

Comment: Yes, that's the requirement

Comment: please see **updated** section of my answer, hope i got your goal right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a job for a simple play, I think.

```
- hosts: mongodb-active
  tasks:
    - shell: /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add("{{ item }}:27017"))'
      loop: "{{ groups['mongodb-arbiter'] }}"
```

Otherwise, it is possible to include task

```
$ cat mongo-eval.yml
- shell: /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add("{{ item }}:27017"))'
  loop: "{{ groups['mongodb-active'] }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
```

and delegate from there

```
- name: Add secondaries
  run_once: true
  include_tasks: mongo-eval.yml
  loop: "{{ groups['mongodb-arbiter'] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: delegate_host
```

For details see [Execute an entire yaml task file one host after the other in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145065/execute-an-entire-yaml-task-file-one-host-after-the-other-in-ansible).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the playbook is written in a way that for all hosts, roles are mapped and inside roles folder , we have separate yaml files with tasks. I will have to change entire structure just for this task. Is there no way, I can use delegate function to run this task only on active server?